# js => input[type=file]

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как загрузить через js в `input[type=file] name="document"` картинку (**скрыто**), чтобы при `submit`'e формы он получил массив данного `input`'a `$_FILES['document']`

P.S *картинка хранится на самом сервере*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input[type='file']` - это единственный (в целом) способ взаимодействия JS и файловой системы.
Поэтому он особо тщательно контролируется безопасностью браузера и, как следствие, многие действия у него урезаны/защищены/не поддаются изменению.

Я уже молчу о том, как ты собираешься пересылать картинку с сервера как файл от клиента. А главное - зачем это нужно. Стоит пересмотреть архитектуру и найти нормальный подход.

В принципе можно извратиться (как всегда и во всём:)), но вряд ли садомазохизм на несколько экранов является приемлемой ценой.

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="file">` может заполнить только пользователь.
Передавайте путь к файлу на серверу в `<input type="hidden">`

Comment: это самый крайний вариант) может как-то без заведения нового input'a?